# What conventions or traditions concern translation of legal abbreviations?

Tags: translation, language

I am currently working on a legal translation, a judgment from Estonian to English.

What is the conventional solution with regard to translating abbreviations of acts?

In my situation, there's the Act on Granting International Protection to Aliens mentioned in the text of the judgment. It's *välismaalasele rahvusvahelise kaitse andmise seadus* in Estonian, abbreviated *VRKS*. Does it make sense to keep the established (Estonian) abbreviation, or use a made-up English one (AGIPA, for example)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is standard to not translate official citation abbreviations, so UrhG stays UrhG, and RT is RT. If a citation is of the form "Act 2 of 12 May 1961" that would be translated, rather than "Lov av 12. mai 1961 nr. 2". [RT I 2006, 2, 3](https://www.riigiteataja.ee/en/eli/530102013009/consolide) officially uses your translation of the title, and all English citations of the law that I can find use the translation and not the Estonian title. "AGIPA" is [not unprecedented](https://www.google.com/search?q=agipa%20estonia&oq=agipa%20estonia&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.20432.22454.0.22662.8.8.0.0.0.0.215.951.3j4j1.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.654...0j0i30k1j0i22i30k1.0.IUsnY67XSKk), but not as common as the [non-abbreviated English](https://www.google.com/search?q=Act%20on%20Granting%20International%20Protection%20to%20Aliens&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (which turns out to be [more popular](https://www.google.com/search?q=v%C3%A4lismaalasele%20rahvusvahelise%20kaitse%20andmise%20seadus&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) that the actual Estonian name).